# Where is Angular-2-Release on https://code.angularjs.org?

Tags: javascript, angular, cdn

I've heard that angular 2 has finally been released. I'm unfortunately not a fan of using npm and bower to automagically load my components. I like to keep my dependencies ultra-thin and understand them all. I also prefer to reference my frameworks from CDN's wherever possible.

When visiting [https://code.angularjs.org/](http://code.angularjs.org) I see right up to `2.0.0-beta.9` and no further. Where do I find the libs for 2.0.0-release online?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[unpkg](https://unpkg.com/#/) serves up packages from npm. You can access/download the latest relevant angular libs there. Here are some of them:

- https://unpkg.com/@angular/core@2.0.2
- https://unpkg.com/@angular/common@2.0.2

Comment: any ideas how to see what's inside the packages? I'm looking for the SFX for example.

Comment: @Spider Are you talking about looking at the corresponding `package.json`? If so, just add /package.json e.g. https://unpkg.com/@angular/common@2.0.2/package.json